# List element getAttribute("value") returns wrong values after calling another function (swapping elements)

Tags: javascript, dom, getattribute

I am still learning `Javascript` and don't understand why I get wrong values when calling `getAttribute('data-value')` from `removeButton` **after** swapping elements with `swapping()` function.

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector('.addButton');
const swapButton = document.querySelector('.swapButton');
var input = document.querySelector('.input');
const draggable_list = document.getElementById('draggable-list');

let items; 
const array = [];
const listItems = [];
let dragStartIndex;

class item {
    constructor(itemName) {
        this.createDiv(itemName);
    }
    createDiv(itemName) {
        let input = document.createElement('input');
        input.value = itemName;
        input.disabled = true;
        input.classList.add('item_input');
        input.type = 'text';
        
        let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
        removeButton.innerHTML = 'REMOVE';
        removeButton.classList.add('removeButton');

        draggable_list.appendChild(items);
        items.appendChild(removeButton);

        removeButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            let itemNumber = event.target.closest('li').getAttribute('data-value');
            console.log("The deleted number has a value of: ", itemNumber); //returns wrong 'data-value' numbers
            if (event && event.target.parentElement) {
                this.remove(event.target.parentElement, input.value);
            }
        });
    }
    //Remove numbers
    remove(item, value) {
        draggable_list.removeChild(item);

        //delete from array
        let indexArray = array.indexOf(value);
        array.splice(indexArray,1);

        //delete from listItems
        listItems.splice(indexArray,1);

        //redfine indexes of li elements after deletion 
        array.forEach((numbers,index) => {
            items.setAttribute('data-index', index);
            items.setAttribute('data-value', numbers);
        } );
    }
}
//Create numbers
async function create() {
    if (input.value != '') {
        array.push(input.value);
        array.forEach((numbers,index) => {
            //if numbers already exists in the UI, then pass?
            items = document.createElement('li');
            items.setAttribute('data-index', index);
            items.setAttribute('data-value', numbers);
            items.innerHTML = `
            <div class="draggable" draggable="true">
                <p class="phone-number" id="div">${numbers}</p>
                <i class="fas fa-grip-lines"></i>
            </div>`;
        } );
        listItems.push(items); //used for swapping
        new item(input.value);
        input.value = ''
    }
}
// Swap list items 
function swapItems(fromIndex, toIndex) {
    const itemOne = listItems[fromIndex].querySelector('.draggable');
    const itemTwo = listItems[toIndex].querySelector('.draggable');

    //swap UI items
    listItems[fromIndex].appendChild(itemTwo);
    listItems[toIndex].appendChild(itemOne);

    //swap array items
    [array[fromIndex], array[toIndex]] = [array[toIndex], array[fromIndex]];
    console.log("This is array after swapping: ",array);

    //redefine li index and values
    array.forEach((numbers,index) => {
        items.setAttribute('data-index', index);
        items.setAttribute('data-value', numbers);

        console.log("The values of the numbers aftwer swapping are: ", numbers); //'data-value' numbers are correct here
    } )
}

function swapping(){
    const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable'); 
    const dragListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-list li'); 

    draggables.forEach(draggable => {
        draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
    });

    dragListItems.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
        item.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
    });
}

function dragStart() {
    dragStartIndex = +this.closest('li').getAttribute('data-index');
  }
function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
function dragDrop() {
    const dragEndIndex = +this.getAttribute('data-index');
    swapItems(dragStartIndex, dragEndIndex);
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', create);
swapButton.addEventListener('click', swapping);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4690c1252a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1><span class="styling">Add a  number</span> </h1>
    <div class="input_div">
        <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Add Task" />
        <button class="addButton">+</button>
        <button class="swapButton">SWAP</button>
    </div>

    <ul class="draggable-list" id="draggable-list"></ul>
    <script src="code.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I try inserting the numbers 1, 2, 3 for example, I swap 1 with 2. Then delete 1, `itemNumber` will have a vlue of 2 instead of 1. Why is that?

Comment: Don't use getAttribute/setAttribute to get/set data. Use dataset.

Comment: Also it seems that the problem is that "items" is always referring to the last created div element it is not referring to all of the different div elements.

Comment: You also need to update the remove function to remove the current value not the old one. Not to be rude but honestly this code is an absolute mess.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yeah I know it's a mess i'm still learning JS. If you have anything else to point out about the code it would be appreciated as it helps me understand better.

Comment: I am sure if I looked into it more I could probably remove some redundancies, but that is beyond the scope of the problem, plus I didn't want to completely change the code if there was any actual reasoning behind the choices made, and I already put in nearly an hour debugging it to fix the original problem so I am gonna leave improving it further up to you. It is good to work things out yourself if you can, it works better than just having the answer handed to you. Like you said you are learning and I'm sure you'll improve with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const addButton = document.querySelector('.addButton');
const swapButton = document.querySelector('.swapButton');
var input = document.querySelector('.input');
const draggable_list = document.getElementById('draggable-list');

let items;
const array = [];
const listItems = [];
let dragStartIndex;

class item {
  constructor(itemName) {
    this.createDiv(itemName);
  }
  createDiv(itemName) {
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = itemName;
    input.disabled = true;
    input.classList.add('item_input');
    input.type = 'text';

    let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.innerHTML = 'REMOVE';
    removeButton.classList.add('removeButton');

    draggable_list.appendChild(items);
    items.appendChild(removeButton);

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      let itemNumber = event.target.closest('li').dataset.value;
      console.log("The deleted number has a value of: ", itemNumber);
      if (event && event.target.parentElement) {
        this.remove(event.target.parentElement, itemNumber);
      }
    });
  }
  //Remove numbers
  remove(item, value) {
    draggable_list.removeChild(item);

    //delete from array
    let indexArray = array.indexOf(value);
    array.splice(indexArray, 1);

    //delete from listItems
    listItems.splice(indexArray, 1);

    //redfine indexes of li elements after deletion 
    array.forEach((numbers, index) => {
      draggable_list.children[index].dataset.index = index;
      draggable_list.children[index].dataset.value = numbers;
    });
  }
}
//Create numbers
async function create() {
  if (input.value != '') {
    array.push(input.value);
    array.forEach((numbers, index) => {
      //if numbers already exists in the UI, then pass?
      items = document.createElement('li');
      items.dataset.index = index;
      items.dataset.value = numbers;
      items.innerHTML = `
                <div class="draggable" draggable="true">
                    <p class="phone-number" id="div">${numbers}</p>
                    <i class="fas fa-grip-lines"></i>
                </div>`;
    });
    listItems.push(items); //used for swapping
    new item(input.value);
    input.value = ''
  }
}
// Swap list items 
function swapItems(fromIndex, toIndex) {
  const itemOne = listItems[fromIndex].querySelector('.draggable');
  const itemTwo = listItems[toIndex].querySelector('.draggable');

  //swap UI items
  listItems[fromIndex].prepend(itemTwo);
  listItems[toIndex].prepend(itemOne);

  //swap array items
  [array[fromIndex], array[toIndex]] = [array[toIndex], array[fromIndex]];
  console.log("This is array after swapping: ", array);

  //redefine li index and values
  array.forEach((numbers, index) => {
    draggable_list.children[index].dataset.index = index;
    draggable_list.children[index].dataset.value = numbers;

    console.log("The values of the numbers after swapping are: ", numbers);
  })
}

function swapping() {
  const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
  const dragListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-list li');

  draggables.forEach(draggable => {
    draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  });

  dragListItems.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    item.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
  });
}

function dragStart() {
  dragStartIndex = +this.closest('li').dataset.index;
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragDrop() {
  const dragEndIndex = +this.dataset.index;
  swapItems(dragStartIndex, dragEndIndex);
}

addButton.addEventListener('click', create);
swapButton.addEventListener('click', swapping);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4690c1252a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1><span class="styling">Add a number</span> </h1>
  <div class="input_div">
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Add Task" />
    <button class="addButton">+</button>
    <button class="swapButton">SWAP</button>
  </div>

  <ul class="draggable-list" id="draggable-list"></ul>
  <script src="code.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I didn't know that 'dataset' existed. This solved my problem

Comment: @Filzo Dataset wasn't the only problem, but yeah, dataset is the proper way to handle data attributes.